# Using localhost database API on iOS device

Tags: ios, angular, typescript, ionic-framework

I'm currently working on an application tied to a nodejs localhost database API. When I test on the iOS simulator, I am getting API data back successfully. However, when I try to test on the iOS device, the application is still making a HTTP request to the localhost API and failing to retrieve the API data.

My question is, is it possible to somehow set up the localhost database API to work on the actual iOS device? if so, what is the best way of going about it?

thank you

Comment: You do realize that "localhost" means the host that the app is running on, right? So when you run your iOS app on a real iOS device, the database must also be running on the iOS device, not your computer.

Comment: Yes, I do realize that. But was wondering if there's any xcode setting I could potentially use while my device is connected to my test machine so it points to `localhost` on my test machine rather than look for it on my iOS device.

Comment: When the app is on your iOS device and the database is on your computer, then the database is no longer on "localhost". It's on a different host. You would need to change the app's code or configuration to point to your computer instead of localhost.

Comment: So it seems the best way to go about this is to put my 'localhost' data on a live server so its no longer local :/ was hoping there was an easier way.. thank you though~!

Comment: @GeorgeCastan100, what you are looking for is not localhost (`127.0.0.1`), but some local network, maybe (`192.168.x.y`) or (`10.z.x.y`); your web-server (if you have any) can manage that nicely for you, if you configure it.

Answer (score 1):

There is a simple fix that will allow your iOS app to connect to your localhost server. What you need is a tunnel that will push your HTTP GET, POST, PUT, and DELETE messages from a device to your local server and return your localhost response back to the client. I wrote a blog article on this very thing with a video that walks you through it. I used ngrok.com. I **DO NOT** get any kickbacks for recommending them. You can have your localhost server interacting with your deployed mobile app, as well as your app running on your simulator.

The Blog Post: http://markzfilter.com/connect-ios-android-app-local-host-server/

The Service I Use (FREE): https://ngrok.com/